# Окончание в слове

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Данные санкции распространяются на всех участников финансовых правоотношений — РФ, субъектов РФ, муниципальные образования".
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать: *субъектов РФ/субъекты РФ*?

Answer (score 1):

Выбор окончания в винительном падеже зависит от одушевленности существительного. **Субъекты** РФ - неодушевленное существительное (это административные образования, а не живые люди). Кроме того, в вашем предложении нужно не тире, а двоеточие, поскольку есть обобщающее слово *всех*, за которым следуют конкретизирующие однородные члены предложения. Поэтому нужно писать: *"Данные санкции распространяются на всех участников финансовых правоотношений: РФ, субъекты РФ, муниципальные образования"*.

Answer (score 0):

Санкции распространяются (на что?) на субъекты - неодушевленное существительное в винительном пдеже.